# At most one record can be returned by this subquery - update query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'll try to update one table as the following :

```
UPDATE T_Payment 
SET Payment_Group_No = ? 
WHERE (T_Payment.Payment_Type_no = 
                        (SELECT T_Payment_type.Payment_type_no 
                         FROM T_Payment_type 
                         WHERE T_Payment_type.Payment_Group_No = ?)) 
                         AND (Payment_Date BETWEEN ? AND ?)
```

Note: select query will return many values.

Comment: Simply change `WHERE` equality `=` to `IN`.

Comment: Access is very limited in a database sense. If this is a production system, I'd highly recommend migrating it as soon as you can. It'll be a pain, but it'll save you a ton of headaches like this. Plus your stability and reliability will significantly improve.

Comment: Also, your Note and your Question Title say two different things. Does the WHERE subquery return more than one result? If so, please update the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use alias name in the subquery because you are using the same table which you update in